# Requesting a SAML 2.0 security token from a WS-Trust STS using WIF 4.5

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wif, ws-trust

I am able to request a SAML 1.1 token using by specifying TokenType=SecurityTokenTypes.Saml in the RequestSecurityToken message. I am able to convert this to a ClaimsPrincipal and view the claims.

However, when I want to request a SAML 2.0 token by changing TokenType to the namespace "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0", I get an exception that includes the following.

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Cannot read KeyIdentifierClause from element
>   'Reference' with namespace
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'.
>   Custom KeyIdentifierClauses require custom SecurityTokenSerializers,
>   please refer to the SDK for examples.'

I was wondering if SAML 2.0 tokens are support when being requested from a WS-Trust 1.3 security token service, and if so, how is it requested? The SecurityTokenTypes constants class provided by Microsoft only contains a single "Saml" that doesn't specify the version, and funny enough, references a Microsoft-specific namespace.

I know that Microsoft has provided supporting classes for SAML 2.0 tokens, such as Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, but I seem to be unable to actually request one from the STS.

Here is my code below.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.Xml;

namespace WsTrustActiveSTSClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string relyingPartyId = "http://localhost/myApp";
        private const string stsEndpoint = "https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, false);

            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;


            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(stsEndpoint);

            WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "admin";

            WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel) factory.CreateChannel();

            RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(relyingPartyId),              
                Claims =
                {
                    new RequestClaim("http://wso2.org/claims/givenname"),
                    new RequestClaim("http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress")
                },
                //TokenType = SecurityTokenTypes.Saml
                TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0"
            };

            GenericXmlSecurityToken genericXmlSecurityToken = (GenericXmlSecurityToken) channel.Issue(rst, out RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr);          

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n\n", genericXmlSecurityToken, genericXmlSecurityToken.TokenXml.OuterXml);

            SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlers = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection(
                new SecurityTokenHandler[]
                {
                    new SamlSecurityTokenHandler(), 
                    new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler()
                }
            );
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction = new AudienceRestriction();
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(relyingPartyId));

            TrustedIssuerNameRegistry trustedIssuerNameRegistry = new TrustedIssuerNameRegistry();
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = trustedIssuerNameRegistry;

            SecurityToken token =
                tokenHandlers.ReadToken(
                    new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericXmlSecurityToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(tokenHandlers.ValidateToken(token).First());

            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Auth Type : " + claimsPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType);
            Console.WriteLine("Is Authed : " + claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            foreach (Claim c in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", c.Type, c.Value);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class TrustedIssuerNameRegistry : IssuerNameRegistry
        {
            public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
            {
                return "Trusted Issuer";
                // throw new SecurityTokenException("Untrusted issuer.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I don't specify a TokenType in the RST this is the SOAP message that gets sent to the WS-Trust STS.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:bb24c76a-b737-4a9b-8526-26b84a28bbe8</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2017-10-17T14:50:01.517Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2017-10-17T14:55:01.517Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-b6a803fc-b1fe-4186-8c3e-dcf4b1a647e5-1">
            <o:Username>admin</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
         <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
               <wsa:Address>http://localhost/myApp</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
         </wsp:AppliesTo>
         <trust:Claims xmlns:i="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" Dialect="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
            <i:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname" Optional="false"/>
            <i:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress" Optional="false"/>
         </trust:Claims>
         <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
         <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
      </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here is the response from WSO2 Identity Server.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
         <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1">
               <wsu:Created>2017-10-17T14:50:02.407Z</wsu:Created>
               <wsu:Expires>2017-10-17T14:55:02.407Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
         </wsse:Security>
         <wsa:Action>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RSTR/Issue</wsa:Action>
         <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:bb24c76a-b737-4a9b-8526-26b84a28bbe8</wsa:RelatesTo>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
               <wst:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1</wst:TokenType>
               <wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
                  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                     <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_d8c5ef71f6665284b3ba5f7aca69f08b</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                  </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
               </wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
               <wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                     <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_d8c5ef71f6665284b3ba5f7aca69f08b</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                  </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
               </wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
               <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                  <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                     <wsa:Address>http://localhost/myApp</wsa:Address>
                  </wsa:EndpointReference>
               </wsp:AppliesTo>
               <wst:Lifetime>
                  <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-10-17T14:50:02.236Z</wsu:Created>
                  <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-10-17T14:55:02.236Z</wsu:Expires>
               </wst:Lifetime>
               <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
                  <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" AssertionID="_d8c5ef71f6665284b3ba5f7aca69f08b" IssueInstant="2017-10-17T14:50:02.282Z" Issuer="https://localhost" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1">
                     <Conditions NotBefore="2017-10-17T14:50:02.236Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-10-17T14:55:02.236Z">
                        <AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                           <Audience>http://localhost/myApp</Audience>
                        </AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                     </Conditions>
                     <AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2017-10-17T14:50:02.236Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
                        <Subject>
                           <NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin</NameIdentifier>
                           <SubjectConfirmation>
                              <ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</ConfirmationMethod>
                           </SubjectConfirmation>
                        </Subject>
                     </AuthenticationStatement>
                     <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                           <ds:Reference URI="#_d8c5ef71f6665284b3ba5f7aca69f08b">
                              <ds:Transforms>
                                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="code ds kind rw saml samlp typens #default xsd xsi"/>
                                 </ds:Transform>
                              </ds:Transforms>
                              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                              <ds:DigestValue>8w9YHsb+YIyUCzGjqh6q0JrjxTI=</ds:DigestValue>
                           </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>Evm0H2+hOMWdsrK0Rp8HPCDDldMJ+AHPgv4hrqKW6IuPGFT25DhTRoIc+cPuerFOABYX5B1Om0v4VlmqsalpK2V7tdzHlrDbrOCiENL4FhdATd48o/IiRjde8XM0B7gHAIJoMSimg3Fc/jPXH4kyMsLAWM+l0GdK8VxKVLPtrhY=</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                           <ds:X509Data>
                              <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                           </ds:X509Data>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                     </ds:Signature>
                  </Assertion>
               </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
            </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
         </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, WSO2 Identity Server is returning a mixture of SAML 1.0 and SAML 1.1 namespaces.

Comment: I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 as the WS-Trust STS.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used WSO Identity Server but this code worked fine with Thinktecture IdentityServer. I've replaced the endpoint address and realm with the information from your example.

```
public static SecurityToken GetToken(string userName, string password)
{
    const string stsEndpoint = "https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts";
    const string realm = "http://localhost/myApp";

    var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
        new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
        stsEndpoint) { TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13 };

    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(realm),
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer
    };

    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
    var token = channel.Issue(rst);
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Just looking this over I would think it would work with WSO2 Identity Server as well, the only thing is that it doesn't specify a TokenType in the RequestSecurityToken element. I am assuming this leaves it up to the STS to return its default token type.

Comment: Are you getting a SAML 2.0 token back in the response from Thinktecture Identity Server?

Comment: @Jeffrey It was relatively long time ago but I think it was always SAML 2.0 assertion. As you said IdentityServer was set to issue SAML 2.0 tokens by default.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes a lot of sense. I see there is support for SAML 2.0 artifacts because I see them in the libraries. It's just how do you specifically request SAML 2.0 when talking to the WS-Trust endpoint. WIF 4.5 has issues with the SOAP XML every time I try it. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Just throwing a curved ball here. WIF is WS-Fed and that only supports SAML 1.1 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can get SAML2.0 tokens from a WS-Trust 1.3 STS, but remember that:

1. It is up to the STS to honor your request. For instance, it might always generate a specific type of token, regardless of what was requested.
2. Not all STS's can generate SAML2.0 tokens. I know WIF 4.5 allows that, but does your STS use it? I'm not sure that the older version (WIF 1.0/3.5) can generate SAML2.0 tokens.

Assuming that your specific STS does honor these requests and can generate SAML2.0 tokens, then try this:

`TokenType = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"`

or, if it still doesn't work, maybe:

`AuthenticationType = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"`

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally found out setting the tokenType of RST to saml2.0 URL will make STS returning SAML 2.0 assertion. The most interesting thing is nowhere from Microsoft documents this.

Try something like this:

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue);
        rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("https://RelyingParty/*");
        rst.KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer;
        rst.TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0";

        using (var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory("WS2007HttpBinding_IWSTrust13_Saml20Sync"))
        {
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = userPassword;

            var channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                _authToken = channel.Issue(rst);
            }
            catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
            {
                channel.Abort();
                throw new SecurityTokenException(ex.InnerException.Message, ex);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            UserIdenity = CreateUserIdentityFromSecurityToken(_authToken);
        }
```